# scrolling text animation, I want it to translate to a specific element on hover CSS / ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I have a sentence and I have one word called "highlight" that is found in the sentence. So before the sentence is mapped into jsx HTML, it goes through the sentence and it looks for the highlight word and matches it with the word in the sentence and makes it a  with a special className called "highlight" and it compiles it into a list called textList. The textList below is just an example of what it would look like.

It currently just scrolls infinitely. On hover, I want it to scroll to the highlight span and center it. Is there any way to do this in just CSS? If not, that's okay as well. I have no clue where to really start.

```js
const textList = ["This is a ", <span className="highlight">part</span>, " of a sentence."]
```

```css
@keyframes carousel {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}

.content {
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: calc(85vh/8);
}

.carousel-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel {
    animation: 120s carousel infinite linear;
    margin: 0;
}

.carousel-container:hover .carousel {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.highlight {
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div className="content">
  <div className="carousel-container">
    <div className="carousel">
      <span>This is a <span className="highlight">part</span> of a sentence.</span>
    </div>
    <div className="carousel">
      <span>This is a <span className="highlight">part</span> of a sentence.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

=========================================================

Based on an answer below that's coded in full js, I'm trying to transform that code into something that works with ReactJS. So I added two useRefs. One on the highlight class and one on the carousel class. I can't get the text to scroll over to the highlight class though.

```
  const handleHover = () => {
let highlightRect = highlightRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
const carouselContainer = carRef.current
// const scrollX = highlightRect.left + window.scrollY - (window.innerWidth / 2) + (highlightRect.width / 2);
// window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: scrollX, behavior: 'smooth' });
const scrollXContainer = highlightRef.current.offsetLeft - (carouselContainer.offsetWidth / 2) + (highlightRect.width / 2);
carouselContainer.scroll({ top: 0, left: scrollXContainer, behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired effect of scrolling to the highlighted  and centering it on hover, you will need to use JavaScript as CSS alone cannot detect hover on a specific element to then scroll another element into view.

**javascript**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.highlight').forEach(highlight => {
  highlight.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    const highlightRect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    const carouselContainer = document.querySelector('.carousel-container');
    const scrollX = highlightRect.left + window.pageXOffset - (window.innerWidth / 2) + (highlightRect.width / 2);
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: scrollX, behavior: 'smooth' });
    
    // If you want to scroll within the container itself, use the following:
    // const scrollXContainer = this.offsetLeft - (carouselContainer.offsetWidth / 2) + (highlightRect.width / 2);
    // carouselContainer.scroll({ top: 0, left: scrollXContainer, behavior: 'smooth' });
  });
});
```

Try this out bro!

Comment: Hey I added an update to my post with reactJS snippet I'm trying.